# Determine PowerPoint Arrow Rotation / Direction

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to determine the rotation of an arrow shape:

```
AutoShapeType = Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeMixed
```

or, in other words, the direction it is pointing to. I can't find anything in the PowerPoint object model that appears to support this. Is this possible and, if so, how?

VBA or VB.NET solutions preferred, although I can work with C#, too. Solution should work in PowerPoint 2010 and later with:

```
AutoShapeType = Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeMixed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.  Shyam gets credit for the assist.

```
Private Function GetLineRotation(shp As PowerPoint.Shape) As Single
    Dim sngRotation As Single = 0, sngDegrees As Single
    With shp
      sngDegrees = Math.Atan2(.Height, .Width) * 57.2957795 'convert radians to degrees
      If .VerticalFlip = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
        If .HorizontalFlip = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
          'Line direction: North-West
          sngRotation = sngDegrees
        Else
          'Line direction: North-East
          sngRotation = 360 - sngDegrees
        End If
      Else
        If .HorizontalFlip = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue Then
          'Line direction: South-West
          sngRotation = 360 - sngDegrees
        Else
          'Line direction: South-East
          sngRotation = sngDegrees
        End If
      End If
    End With
    Return sngRotation
  End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a standard right pointing arrow then its `AutoShapeType` property will be `msoShapeRightArrow` (33).

Knowing which arrow you have is the first step (so you know which way it points when rotated by the default 0 degrees). You then need to know the shapes rotation which assuming it's the first shape on the first slide, you get in degrees from:

```
Dim oShp as Shape
Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
Debug.Print oShp.Rotation
```

So if the right pointing arrow (type 33) has been rotated to make it point down, the rotation value changes to 90.

Comment: This does not work for AutoShapeType = msoShapeMixed.  To be clear, the shape I am referring to is simply a line shape with an arrow head.  So, maybe it's easier to think of the question this way:  what is the rotation of a line shape?

Comment: Ah - it's a line shape, not an arrow shape. OK, but I can still use oShp.Rotation to read and write the rotation in degrees on my system. I added a line with a single arrow head in PowerPoint and then in the VBA immediate window (Atl+11 and then Ctrl+G) I typed this:

?activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Rotation
 0 
activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Rotation=90
?activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Rotation
 90

Comment: Well, you might be able to set the rotation this way, but I need to get the rotation of the line / arrow.  If you draw a line at an angle, then read the Rotation property, it is zero.

Comment: In that case, the line isn't rotated so Rotation will correctly return 0.  So if you want to know it's orientation and not the rotation as originally stated, you need to read the start and finish X/Y coordinates using .Top .Left .Width and .Height

Comment: Right.  I am really referring to visual "rotation" and not the "Rotation" property.  For non-line shapes, these are the same.  However, there are no start / end coordinates for a line shape, so you cannot tell in which direct the arrowhead is pointing.  For example, how could you tell if an arrow is rotated 90 deg or 270 deg from the Height / Width properties (Top / Left properties aren't useful here)?

Answer (score 1):

This example may be useful to you : 
Determine The Direction Of A Line Shape - http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00038.htm

Answer (score 0):

The VBA solution is `Shape.Rotation` in the PowerPoint Library. After getting a reference to your shape the `Rotation` Property can be read and written to adjust the orientation in degrees.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff744648.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for arrows shapes with AutoShapeType  = msoShapeMixed.  Note that there is no rotation handle used for rotating the shape with the mouse with this type of shape.  So, the Rotation property always returns zero.